# custom landing page overrides return URL if user is not logged in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've got a custom landing based on roles

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        var theLoggedInEmail = model.Email;
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);
                var roles = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);
                if (roles.Contains("user"))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Custom_dashboard", routeValues: new { id = User.Identity.GetUserId() });
                    //Send a mail to user to notify them of logging in
                }
                if (roles.Contains("Admin"))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin_dashboard", routeValues: new { id = User.Identity.GetUserId() });
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt. Please try again with correct email and password");
                return View(model);
        }           
    }
```

and another module to display some information if user is logged in.

The View Page

```
    @if ( (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) && (User.IsInRole("Employer")) ) {
        [Information to be displayed...]
    }
    @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false)
    {
       <h4 class="text-center">
           @Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Account", new { @returnUrl = ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery }, null)
       </h4>
    }
```

If user is not logged in, the system redirects the user to the login page and authenticates that user, If successful, the system displays the view but the custom landing page is displayed instead.

How do i get it to work please

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @DaImTo  if the user is logged in, it works fine as the information is displayed but if the user is not logged in, the system redirects the user to the login page, the  custom landing page is displayed after logging in but i want the view with the information displayed not the custom landing page

Comment: @mjwills yes! only to see  the information

Comment: @mjwills `http://localhost:44257/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FUser%2FDetails%2F61eb36a6-f083-4565-a9cc-b175838b0847`

Comment: @mjwills Thanks a lot. What i did was to check if returnURL != null  and return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl) inside the if condition checking for the roles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `Login` route to redirect to `Login` route (without querystring) if `returnURL` is set to the kind of `returnURL` that you don't want to honour.

Then the `returnURL` will be cleared, and it should work the way you want